# How to configure QoS on a D-Link DSL-2750U (1.16f)?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lag, qos

My internet is so slow when family starts using it along with me.

I get crazy lags in-game (League of Legends) and browsing as well (even Facebook). But when I'm alone on the network, which rarely happens, everything works smoothly.

The router is D-Link DSL-2750U (1.16f).

I'm using a laptop which only supports Wi-Fi.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You just gave a textbook description of a widespread router bug known as bufferbloat. Typical QoS (prioritizing one kind of traffic over another, or reserving bandwidth for certain devices) is not a proper solution to bufferbloat. The solution is to run a smart queue management (SQM) algorithm on your router. If that "Scheduling Strategy" pop-up menu has "CAKE", "FQ-CoDel", "CoDel", or "PIE", select one of those (I listed them from best to worst). What is your bufferbloat grade on the [Waveform Bufferbloat Test](https://www.waveform.com/tools/bufferbloat)?

Comment: watch the new photos pls...